# Display actual Image from Switch Function instead of URL text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a script and almost have it working except I need a `div` (id) to show an actual image and not just the URL of the image.

You can see it in [this **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PL6fU/29/).

Also, I would like to display a background image to show as a default image... then once you select inputs, the image change over the background image.

**Here is the part of the script that generates the URL**

```
$('#show_image_text').html(image_name); // Put the image URL
    $('#show_image').html(image_name); // Put the image value in the formula image field src.
});
```

Here is the `div` where I am wanting to display the image. It may need to be styled for `width`, `height`, and `background-image`

```
<div id="show_image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code as follows:

`$('#show_image').css('background-image',"url('"+image_name+"')");`

Also, the div `#show_image` doesn't have any height set, so the image won't be visible unless you set it's height explicitly

```
#show_image{
 height:50px;
 width:200px;
 background-image:url('path to default image'); //you can set a default image like this, which will be overridden once you set the image in code...
}
```

updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/PL6fU/31/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('#show_image').html("<img src='" + image_name + "' />");
```

instead of:

```
$('#show_image').html(image_name);
```